# Questions about first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We all know $\forall x A(x)\Longleftrightarrow A(a_1) \wedge A(a_2) \cdots \wedge A(a_n)$, if the set is finite. If the set is countable $\forall x A(x)\Longleftrightarrow \wedge A(a_i)(i = 1,2,\cdots)$. It is still true when the set is uncountable, but how can we prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that we allow conjunctions with uncountably many conjuncts such that we can write e.g.

$$ \bigwedge_{i \in \mathbb{R}} A_i$$

Assume that our first-order formulae can mention constants in some universe $U$. By definition, a universally quantified formula $\forall x. A(x)$ is true if for every $c \in U$ we have that $A(c)$ is true.

Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set. By definition, a conjunction $ \bigwedge_{i \in I} A_i$ is true if for every $i \in I$ we have that $A_i$ is true.

Let our universe $U = \bigcup{i \in I} \{ a_i \}$. It then now easy to see that $\forall x.A(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\bigwedge_{i \in I} A(a_i)$.